# spring mybatis how to determine if using batch mode correctly

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper

How do determine if one is using `batch` mode correctly? I am using spring boot with mybatis (`org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0`)

### Setup

```java
// Controller
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public Post updateById(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Post post) {
    return this.postService.updateById(id, post);
}

// PostMapper
@Update("UPDATE POST SET title = #{p.title}, body = #{p.body}, createdAt = #{p.createdAt}, createdBy = #{p.createdBy}, updatedAt = #{p.updatedAt}, updatedBy = #{p.updatedBy} WHERE id = #{id}")
public boolean updateById(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("p") Post post);

@Flush
List<BatchResult> flush();
```

### First test - normal loop

So I ran the `update` query 4 times

```java
// Service
@Transactional
public Post updateById(Integer id, Post post) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        this.postMapper.updateById(id++, post);
    }
        
    return post;
}
```

Here's the log. It looks normal to me, processing the update one by one.

```
2021-10-31 22:44:48.542  INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-24 - Starting...
2021-10-31 22:44:48.606  INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-24 - Start completed.
2021-10-31 22:44:48.610 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Creating a new SqlSession
2021-10-31 22:44:48.610 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.610 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction         : JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1448464118 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@26c16917] will be managed by Spring
2021-10-31 22:44:48.611 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:44:48.611 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 65(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:44:48.615 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:44:48.615 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.616 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:44:48.616 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:44:48.616 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 66(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:44:48.619 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:44:48.620 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.620 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:44:48.620 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:44:48.620 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 67(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:44:48.622 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:44:48.623 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.623 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:44:48.623 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:44:48.624 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 68(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:44:48.626 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:44:48.626 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.626 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.627 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
2021-10-31 22:44:48.627 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@1d4e918f]
```

### Second test - introduce `batch` executor

Create a different `bean` that is with `batch` mode

```java
@Configuration
class MapperConfig {

    // seem like once I create the `batchSqlSession`, I have to also create the default `sqlSessionTemplate`
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean("batchSqlSession")
    public SqlSessionTemplate sqlBatchSessionTemplate(SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory) {
        return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory, ExecutorType.BATCH);
    }
}
```

Then in the service class

```java
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PostService {
    private final PostMapper postMapper;
    @Qualifier("batchSqlSession") final SqlSessionTemplate batchSqlSession;
}

@Transactional
public Post updateById(Integer id, Post post) {
    int batchSize = 2;

    PostMapper pm = this.batchSqlSession.getMapper(PostMapper.class);
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        pm.updateById(id++, post);

        if (i % batchSize == 0 || i == batchSize) {
            System.out.println("flushing batch");
            pm.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run it, the log doesn't look too different except for the log `flushing batch` in between

```
2021-10-31 22:55:25.472  INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-29 - Starting...
2021-10-31 22:55:25.518  INFO 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-29 - Start completed.
2021-10-31 22:55:25.521 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Creating a new SqlSession
2021-10-31 22:55:25.521 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Registering transaction synchronization for SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.521 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.m.s.t.SpringManagedTransaction         : JDBC Connection [HikariProxyConnection@1375396778 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@34ad8866] will be managed by Spring
2021-10-31 22:55:25.522 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:55:25.522 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 65(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:55:25.525 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:55:25.525 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.525 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:55:25.525 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:55:25.526 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 66(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:55:25.527 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:55:25.528 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
flushing batch
2021-10-31 22:55:25.528 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:55:25.529 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.529 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:55:25.529 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:55:25.529 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 67(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:55:25.533 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:55:25.533 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.533 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:55:25.534 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==>  Preparing: UPDATE POST SET title = ?, body = ?, createdAt = ?, createdBy = ?, updatedAt = ?, updatedBy = ? WHERE id = ?
2021-10-31 22:55:25.534 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : ==> Parameters: batchtitle(String), batchbody(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 2021-08-10T11:31:07.530686900(LocalDateTime), stackoverflow(String), 68(Integer)
2021-10-31 22:55:25.536 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.b.s.s.post.PostMapper.updateById       : <==    Updates: 1
2021-10-31 22:55:25.536 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
flushing batch
2021-10-31 22:55:25.537 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Fetched SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090] from current transaction      
2021-10-31 22:55:25.537 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.537 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization committing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.537 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization deregistering SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
2021-10-31 22:55:25.537 DEBUG 1936 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionUtils       : Transaction synchronization closing SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@3bb28090]
```

So was something configured wrongly, hence, I'm not actually making use of the `batch` mode?

If this is not considered as off-topic, is it possible to configure default `batch-size` in `application.properties` or when configuring the batch mode `SqlSessionTemplate` in the `bean` creation?

Thanks

Comment: When configured correctly, there is a `Preparing:` line followed by many `Parameters:` lines in the log. These demos may help: [1](https://github.com/jeffgbutler/mybatis-cockroach-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/cockroachdemo/service/MyBatisAccountService.java) [2](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-60993091)

Comment: Thanks! It seem that I have to be careful when using `@AllArgsConstructor` and `@Qualifier`. Seem like it doesn't pick up correctly hence, it's always using back the default `sqlSession`. I do see single `Preparing` followed followed by many `Parameters` depending on my `chunk` size now. But I also saw that there's `Releasing transactional SqlSession` and `Fetched SqlSession` with each `Parameters` statement. Does that mean that each of them is a separate commit instead of a batch commit? Not sure if there's any difference.

Comment: In other words, does that mean that it's on a different transaction? or are all of them in the same transaction?

Comment: They should be in the same transaction. You should test it, though.

Comment: if different chunk are all in the same transaction, then what's the point of running in chunk? Shouldn't each chunk be in it's own transaction?

Comment: Nope. Here is an excerpt from the JDBC API Spec. "The batch update facility allows multiple SQL statements to be submitted to a data source for processing at once. Submitting multiple SQL statements, instead of individually, can greatly improve performance.". So, the purpose of 'batch update' is to improve performance. And it does not make sense if each 'chunk' is executed in a different [transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help and guidance.